# bind a value having dependency property from one class to another class textbox control in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have two classes Radial.xaml.cs and ToothDimension.xaml.cs, want to bind value of the class  Radial.xaml.cs textbox control  to the dependency property of another class ToothDimension.xaml.cs which works fine. It's not getting bound to text box control. Do I need to change DataContext in Radial.xaml.cs? I tried this:

**Radial.xaml.cs**

```
public Radial()
    {
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new ToothDimension(); 
    }
```

**Radial.xaml**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Length" Text="{Binding DataContext.ToothHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35"/>
```

**ToothDimension.xaml.cs** (in which ToothHeight is declared)

```
 public Double ToothHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ToothHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToothHeightProperty, value); }
    }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty ToothHeightProperty 
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ToothHeight", 
     typeof(double), typeof(ToothDimensions), 
     new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ToothHeightChanged)));

private static void ToothHeightChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double value = (double)e.NewValue;
        ToothMeasurements thisControl = d as ToothMeasurements;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the path of your binding just to `ToothHeight`.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Length" Text="{Binding ToothHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35"/>
```

Though I would suggest you to use the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I've built an application with the code you've provided - it works. Try to set another default-value to your dependency-property to find out whether there are binding issues or you're just struggling with updating your Tooth-Height-property. Your dependency-property would look llike this: `public static readonly DependencyProperty ToothHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ToothHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ToothDimension), new PropertyMetadata(10.0, ToothHeightChanged));`

Comment: ToothHeight is associated to a text box in Tooth Dimension class so , it works fine  .But i want to reuse this ToothHeight and bind it to another textbox control in Radial class . if i use ToothHeight to bind in same class all i have to do is DataContext = this in constructor . Unable to bind in Radial class .I have a constructor in ToothDimension that has a local variable . it looks like this.                                                                public ToothDimension(int toothid)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ToothId = toothid;
        }

Comment: iam unable to update ToothHeight in another class i can update ToothHeight to another text box in same class

Comment: I'm getting confused - not able to understand what you're trying to achieve. I recommend you to separate UI and app logic using the Model-View-ViewModel pattern. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mvvm/4293/getting-started-with-mvvm#t=20161130091014686013) It's not common to set a usercontrol as datacontext to another usercontrol.

Comment: i have a  textbox named "toothheight" in ToothDimension.xaml class that uses ToothHeight as dependency property, i want to use this value of text box that user will set .  I want it in another  Radial class  i have a text box there i want it to be reflected there, when i bind it, it is showing 0. It doesn't show me what the user writes in toothheight text box of ToothDimension class

Comment: i tried to update ToothHeight  the way you said its setting to 10.0 but its not getting what  the user sets in another text box and  gets updated from there.

Comment: If User enters value 7 in ToothDimension text box why it does mot update in radial class text box.  There it shows 0 . @ManDani

Answer (score 0):

It was binding correctly, I got it working .