# Can I show my output in more than one class in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have  a Length text box control in Class X and that uses dependency property and If user enters value for Length (let's say 10), can i get this value  10 in any other label outside my class in  other Class Y . I mean getting whatever value this text box has outside my class X . (Because i want to do something like this  [bind a value having dependency property from one class to another class textbox control in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795848/bind-a-value-having-dependency-property-from-one-class-to-another-class-textbox/40799312?noredirect=1#comment68982615_40799312)) .

Comment: Your data (model) should be managed in some other class that is not your view ( a view model).  That way you can bind multiple views, or multiple controls in a single view to the same data.  This may be overkill for what you are doing, but there are good concepts here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) .

Comment: if i bind to a constant value Iam able to do that but if i want to get  read only display from the textbox iam unable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the other class(es) subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` notification of the originating class. When the property in question changes, copy it to the desired target property.

Comment: i added UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged , Even that is not helping . Can you elaborate more , programmatically

Comment: just got through it had to bind it again to a declared function.